# Python 3.6 Flask ImportError: cannot import name 'flash'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, conda, airflow

I keep having error `ImportError: cannot import name 'flash'` when trying to run `airflow webserver` command.

Various packages have been installed including flask-login, flask, flask-cache, flask-wtf etc. This is on a server without internet connection, I have had to transfer those packages manually and run `conda install <package> --offline`

Full traceback

```
/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cache/jinja2ext.py:33: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.cache is deprecated, use flask_cache instead.
  from flask.ext.cache import make_template_fragment_key
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/bin/airflow", line 27, in <module>
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/bin/cli.py", line 678, in webserver
    app = cached_app(conf)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 161, in cached_app
    app = create_app(config)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/app.py", line 59, in create_app
    from airflow.www import views
  File "/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 46, in <module>
    from flask_login import flash
ImportError: cannot import name 'flash'
```

Thanks.

Comment: `flask_login` has no module `flash`. but `flask` does. change to `from flask import flash`

Comment: do you have the solution for this ImportError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment the python library `flask-login` does not have a module or function called `flash`. Therefore you cannot write in your code, which is present on line 46 in views.py:

`from flask-login import flash`

However, that function is present in the python-library `flask`. Therefore change to:

`from flask import flash`

Comment: actually I didn't write any code. I installed airflow with pip, that error popped out when I did airflow webserver command